# HowTo run sc.exe as admin from within a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I created a windows service program.
this program takes comand line argument */install /uninstall /start /stop* so that the service can easily be installed, uninstalled, started and stopped from command line internally using **sc.exe** started via a process.
If I execute the progam with a argument from a command window started with runas admin my service program behaves like expected.

Now I want to test this behavior from within a unit test.
But what ever I do, the internally called **sc.exe** returns with:
StdOutput:[SC] OpenSCManager ERROR 5:
Access Denied.

I am creating the process with my user credentials.
I am local admin on the system.
What is it I am doing wrong?

the relevant code I am using is shown below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanBe_Installed_Started_Stopped_And_Uninstalled()
    {
        // Arrange
        Assert.IsFalse(this.IdfServiceIsInstalled(), "Service is already installed");

        // Act/Assert
        this.InstallService();
        Assert.IsTrue(this.IdfServiceIsInstalled(), "Service is not Installed");
        //Assert.IsFalse(this.ServiceIsStarted(), "Service is already Started");

        //this.StartService();
        //Assert.IsTrue(this.ServiceIsStarted(), "Service is not started");

        //this.StopService();
        //Assert.IsFalse(this.ServiceIsStarted(), "Service is still started");

        //this.UninstallService();
        //Assert.IsFalse(this.IdfServiceIsInstalled(), "Service is still installed");
    }
    
    private void InstallService()
    {
        try
        {
            // ToDo: find generic way to get the path to IdfService!
            var serviceBinPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Entwicklung\ImageDataForwarder\Output\netcoreapp3.1", "IdfService.exe");
            var fi = new FileInfo(serviceBinPath);
            Assert.IsTrue(fi.Exists);

            var serviceProcess = this.PrepareServiceProcess(serviceBinPath);
            serviceProcess.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add("/install");
            serviceProcess.Start();
            serviceProcess.WaitForExit();

            var reader = serviceProcess.StandardOutput;
            var output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var exitCode = serviceProcess.ExitCode;
            Assert.AreEqual(0, exitCode, output);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Assert.Fail($"IdfServiceIsInstalled failed: {exception}");
        }
    }

    private Process PrepareServiceProcess(string serviceBinPath)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = serviceBinPath,
                UserName = USER_NAME,
                Password = this.GetSecurePassword(),
                Domain = DOMAIN,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                Verb = "runas",
            };

        var serviceProcess = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
        return serviceProcess;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should Mock in this case.

Comment: I think you should set UseShellExecute = true

Comment: I can't mock it, since I need to test "real functionallity"

Comment: If I set UseShellExecute = true the test fails with the message UseShellExecute must be set to false

Comment: It isn't a unit testing

Comment: It is. The shown methods are called from a TestMethod.

Comment: What @PavelAnikhouski means that a *unit test* should not depend on and more so not alter the state of the system.

Comment: agreed! Still I need this lets call it integration test.

Comment: What if you execute the testrunner as admin?

Comment: Have done this by starting VS as Admin -> same problem